# Convert JSON dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert a JSON dictionary to a Pandas DataFrame, but the embedding is tripping me up.

Here is basically what the JSON dict looks like.

```
{
  "report": "{'name':{'data':[{'key 1':'value 1','key 2':'value 2'},{'key 1':'value 1','key 2':'value 2'}]}}"
}
```

In the DataFrame, I want the keys to be the column headers and values in the rows below them.

The extra layer of embedding is throwing me off somewhat from all the usual methods of doing this.

One tricky part is 'name' will change each time I get this JSON dict, so I can't use an exact sting value for 'name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON looks a bit odd. It looks more like a Python dict converted to a string, so you can use `ast.literal_eval` (a built-in function) to convert it to a real dict, and then use `pd.json_normalize` to get it into a dataframe form:

```
import ast

j = ...
parsed_json = ast.literal_eval(j['report'])
df = pd.json_normalize(parsed_json, record_path=[list(parsed_json)[0], 'data'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     key 1    key 2
0  value 1  value 2
1  value 1  value 2
```

Comment: that works, thank you, but one tricky part which I only added a few minutes after the question is, 'name' will change each time I look at this data. Is there a way to do the above, not knowing what the 'name' will be. The nesting will always be the same.

Comment: Try it now, @Jack. It'll dynamically use the first key found in the object instead of just `'name'` :)

Comment: that works like a charm. Many thanks. I would have been all day figuring that out. I always find converting JSON to dfs tough. It's never nicely nested in the real world like the examples I always see given. Thanks again.

Comment: I kinda agree with you actually. There are a ton of questions here about stuff like pivots, merges, and JSON parsing. They should provide more examples.

Comment: A bit of an ask I know, but what exactly is the ast.literal_eval doing in this case? I have looked up some explanations and it’s not really making sense to me.

Comment: Abstract Syntax Tree - a way to programatically manipulate a program's source code. Read more online. The [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module is built-in to Python.

Comment: Basically `ast.literal_eval` says to "evaluate this code as if it were Python code". However, it's perfectly safe to run, but it doesn't just execute any code. Only code such as string or number or dict _literals_; hence `literal_eval`.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll do some more reading. I,ve done a few of these before and didn’t have to use it. But I see it mentioned a lot so it must be useful to know. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you're trying to index the strings (because the value under `report` is a string) using another string.

You just need `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string and a DataFrame constructor. If the "name" is unknown, you can iterate over the `dict.values` after you parse the string.

```
import ast
out = pd.DataFrame(y for x in ast.literal_eval(your_data['report']).values() for y in x['data'])
```

Output:

```
     key 1    key 2
0  value 1  value 2
1  value 1  value 2
```